# Passing JavaScript variable between pages works fine, but DataTables is still erroring

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

For the LIFE of me I cannot figure this out.

**Setup:**

```
page 1: add.php
page 2: upload.php
page 3: return.php
```

On page one, the user uploads a spreadhseet from Excel:

```
<div id="return"></div>    
~~~~~
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){                    
                jsonResponse = data;
                $("#return").load("return.php")

            }           
       });
    }));
});
```

The Excel sheet is sent over to `upload.php` and a JSON response is returned with the data from the cells.

```
echo json_encode($out);
```

This is exactly how it looks in `console.log`

```
jsonResponse = [
 {"dateReceived":"2015-01-01","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"2016-04-05","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 2","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"1982-04-18","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 3","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"}
 ]
```

On success, `return.php` is loaded into the `#return` div that exists on this first page and it attempts to build a `dataTable` with the JSON output... :

```
var table = $('#ltc-table').DataTable( {    
    "data" : jsonResponse,        
    "columns" : [
      { data : 'designCustomer' },
      { data : 'designCustomerLocation' },
      { data : 'dateReceived' }
  ]
});
```

However, I get the error: `Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=ltc-table - Requested unknown parameter 'designCustomer' for row 0.`

**What I don't understand:**

`jsonResponse` is a variable that contains JSON, and when I use `console.log(jsonResponse);` **on** `return.php`, I get the exact string that I pasted above (so I assume `jsonResponse` is a variable I can on this page if `console.log` is reporting it), however, datatables says it can't find the variable, as it's issuing me this error.

If, on `return.php`, I create new code that flat out defines `jsonResponse` there instead:

```
jsonResponse = [
 {"dateReceived":"2015-01-01","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"2016-04-05","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 2","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"1982-04-18","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 3","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"}
];
```

**it works.**

What am I doing wrong?  Is this a problem of me passing the data from one page to another page loaded into a div on that first page?  This is driving me crazy.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax reply will be returning text won't it? I don't see any "json" type specified in the ajax.

Does the data property support JSON. Or does it need javascript objects?
Looking at the docs under "ajax sourced", it implies to use the "ajax" property of the datatable function:
e.g
[Ajax Sourced Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: I can definitely use JSON in the data property, as referenced here: `http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html` .  The issue isn't whether or not this works, as it works fine when I manually create a variable with the JSON data.  (See the code I pasted right above the words "it works" (in bold).  This only doesn't work when I create the variable on `add.php` and try to use it in `return.php`, even though `return.php` is loaded inside of a `div` on `add.php`.

Comment: holy crap........ you're right.  All I needed to do was put `dataType: "json",` into the original ajax call and it worked.  Thank you!!

Comment: So your manual version is providing javascript objects, therefore you're giving it what it expects in that case. But your .php version is giving it json, which threw it off. Cool.